# Does Flows support partial save?

Tags: visual-workflow

We have Flows that creates and updates records. If any of the record fails due to bad data, whole batch of records is failing. And these records roll over to next batch and are consistently failing future batches. Is there a way to configure partial saves in Flows like Database.insert/update operations?

Comment: Though working with flows is really awesome, but I do not think you can achieve all coding tasks using flows. partial save is such thing. you can create an idea in salesforce community.

Comment: Not sure but do check if this [Enable Partial Save for Invocable Actions - Critical Update](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter20/release-notes/rn_forcecom_flow_mgmnt_partial_save_cruc.htm) can help for your use case

Comment: You should be more specific about how the flow is triggered as that is where the "batching" starts

Comment: @cropredy A Batch job with a batch size of 100, is invoking a process builder which in turn calls a Flow. Flow has insert operations and if one of the records fails, it is failing the entire batch of 100 and the failed records are rolling over to next batch and subsequent batches are also failing.

Comment: @Shamina thanks for the link. this update is about invocable actions, not data operations(Create Records, Update Records, Delete Records)

Comment: does the batch job do a Database.update(recs,false)?

Comment: no it doesn't. but i tried doing partial save like you mentioned. but it didn't work. it is still failing entire batch.

Comment: Do you have any error handling in the flow?

Comment: @KrisGoncalves Yes, no error handling. We can use Fault element. But it doesn't support partial save. AFAIK, it only allows us what to do some exception occurs. More like a catch block instead of partial save.

Answer (score 1):

Quick Update to this post - since Spring 20, Create Records does now [support](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?language=en_US&id=release-notes.rn_forcecom_flow_mgmnt_actions_partial_save.htm&release=224&type=5) Partial Save.

[image]